# Webpack bundle, directive not resolved

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angularjs-directive, bundle, angular-webpack

I am trying to bundle using webpack, and also added one custom plugin to dynamic load required modules in bundled file. So, I am able to generate bundle.js file. The directive is not resolved. I can see the directive code in bundle file, but not resolved. The module in which directive is added, that module is also loaded as other component in same module are resolved.
Here is the screenshot for bundle file -
[image]

As in the image you can see the directive resolved. Here is the html tag which doesn't generates the template-
[image]

I am not able to understand, that what might be the reason for directive not resolved.

EDIT : - I did some more analysis, and found that the webpack bundle file have some method to resolve the dependency using require(). So bundle file have all the code but the dependency is resolved by the require method of the bundle file.